# Is there a central limit theorem for $L^p$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

let $Y_i$ be a sequence of identically distributed independent random variables with mean 0 and variance 1.  If $X$ is independent and gaussian with the same mean and variance then does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)$ converge in $L^p$ to $X$?  The central limit theorem usually holds in distribution but I would like to know if there is a stronger convergence where the sum converges to a gaussian random variable.

Comment: I think it might be more worthwhile to ask whether there always exists a Gaussian $X$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$ so that $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\to X$ in $L^r$. In fact I do not know the answer to that (but I would be surprised that this is not a well-known result if the answer does turn out to be "yes.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: assume each $Y_i$ has distribution $\mathcal N(0,1)$, so that $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ independent of $(Y_1,\ldots)$ with $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i \xrightarrow{L^p}X$.

Since $X$ is independent of $(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots)$ the random variable $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i - X$ has distribution $\mathcal N(0,2)$ thus

$$E\left[\left|\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i - X\right|^p\right]$$

is a non-zero constant. It does not converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Upvoted, even though in my opinion the formulation makes it not super clear that you use that $$\text{convergence in }L^r\implies\text{convergence in distribution}.$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Where do you think am I using convergence in distribution ?

Comment: The argument that you use is not rigorous, since $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ according to the CLT, but does not at all itself have to be distributed like $\mathcal N(0, 1)$. So, if I am not mistaken, a rigorous formulation of your argument would look like this: "According to CLT, $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-X\to \mathcal N(0,2)$ in distribution. If it were to go to $0$ in $L^r$, then, **since convergence in $L^r$ implies convergence in distribution**, $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-X\to0$ in distribution. Contradiction.

Comment: $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are each $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and they are **mutually independent**. A [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) implies that $\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ exactly has distribution $\mathcal N(0,n)$. There's no need for asymptotics or the CLT.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, according to the question formulation the $Y_i$ can have any distribution, we only know $\mathsf EY_i =0, \mathsf VY_i=1$.

Comment: I misread, my bad !

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I've reframed my answer as a specific counterexample. You should post your proof in a separate answer since it yields a stronger result.

Comment: Thank you and done!

Answer (score 2):

A summary of the brief discussion with [Gabriel Romon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/66096/):

Given any independent, identically distributed random variables $(Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ with $\mathsf EY_k=0, \mathsf VY_k=1$, if $X$ is independent of $(Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$, then according to the Central Limit Theorem,* $-X+\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty Y_k$ converges in distribution to (slight abuse of notation ahead) $$\mathcal N(0,1)+\mathcal N(0,1)=\mathcal N(0,2)\neq0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

In particular, since convergence in $L^r$ implies convergence in distribution (this can be proven with Markov's inequality for example), it follows that $-X
+\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty Y_k$ can't converge to $0$ in $L^r$.

---

* A more careful formulation: Let $Z_n\overset{\text{Def.}}=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k, n\in\mathbb N$. For any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we have, by independence and the Central Limit Theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(-X\le a\land Z_n\le b)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(-X\le a)\mathsf P(Z_n\le b)=\mathsf P(-X\le a)\mathsf P(\mathcal N(0,1)\le b).$$

Let $\mathsf P_{(-X,\mathcal N(0,1))}$ be the measure on $\mathbb R^2$ that is uniquely determined (exercise: proof that it is unique) by the condition $\mathsf P_{(-X,\mathcal N(0,1))}(A\times B)=\mathsf P(-X\in A)\mathsf P(\mathcal N(0,1)\in B)$ for all measurable $A,B\subset\mathbb R$.

Then by the argument before, $\mathsf P_{(-X,Z_n)}$ converges weakly (in the sense of measures) to $\mathsf P_{(-X,\mathcal N(0,1))}$. Let $h:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R, (x,y)\mapsto x+y$. Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be any continuous, bounded function. Then $f\circ h:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and bounded. By the [Portmanteau Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} f\,\mathrm d\mathsf P_{-X+Z_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} f\circ h\,\mathrm d\mathsf P_{(-X, Z_n)}=\int_{\mathbb R} f\circ h\,\mathrm d\mathsf P_{(-X, \mathcal N(0,1))}=\int_{\mathbb R} f\,\mathrm d\mathsf P_{\mathcal N(0,2)}.$$

Using Portmanteau again, I conclude that $\mathsf P_{-X+Z_n}\to\mathsf P_{\mathcal N(0,2)}$ weakly as $n\to\infty$, which is the same as saying that $-X+Z_n\to\mathcal N(0,2)$ in distribution. This completes the argument.

Comment: I think more care is needed to obtain $\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i -X \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,2)$. You may use the following result: if $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are two sequences of r.v.s such that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$, $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} Y$, $X_n \perp \!\!\! \perp Y_n$ and $X\perp \!\!\! \perp Y$, then $(X_n,Y_n) \xrightarrow{d} (X,Y)$. Here $X_n = X$, $Y_n=\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i $ and $Y=Z$ where $Z$ is an iid copy of $X$. Finally, use the continuous mapping theorem.

Comment: Wow if I keep answering questions on StackExchange, there is no way that I will ever finish my Master's thesis . Anyway, thanks for noting that: I have added a paragraph on the issue raised in your comment.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You could also use characteristic functions to show it converges in distribution to $N(0,2)$ right?  and from that we would get $E(|-X+S_n|) \to 2$?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I'll tag you for the above question as well.  Thanks for the help